# Matplotlib: Plot something new in an axis upon key press

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Each time the user presses a key on the keyboard, a new plot should be drawn. The example below uses just a random plot, in reality, I'll combine it with a statemachine that calls a different `plot()` function on each press.

I have the short minimal code with a random plot:

```
fig = plt.figure(1)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')

def plot(e):
    ax1.cla()
    ax1.plot(np.random.rand(10))

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', plot)

plt.show()
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens. **What is missing or how could I fix it?** I guess I have to somehow redraw the `ax1` or then I completely missunderstand something...

Answer (score 0):

This is my code, I figured it has to do with the plt.figure(1), because if I do that in the plot method it does generate a new graph everytime I press a key.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(1)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')

def plot(e):
    fig = plt.figure(1)
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
    ax1.cla()
    ax1.plot(np.random.rand(10))

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', plot)

plt.show()
```

Comment: how do i iterate over different plots on button press?
i mean, it's easy to generate random plot in the function but what if i want to plot sequence of plots one after the other that i have in some other variable?

Answer (score 0):

add following line to the function:

```
fig.canvas.draw_idle()
```