# iteratively plot numpy or torch arrays as images and switch on keypress

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

i came across this post that shows how to iteratively plot random plots by kyepress :
[link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38396318/matplotlib-plot-something-new-in-an-axis-upon-key-press)

it works fine.

i can't modify it so my tensor of shape (64,64,798) will present images one after the other.

here's my attempt:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch

data = torch.rand((64,64,798))

fig = plt.figure(1)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
i=0

def plot(e):
    fig = plt.figure(1)
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
    ax1.cla()
    ax1.imshow(data[:,:,i])
    i+=1

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', plot)

plt.show()
```

getting back an error:

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment

i expected this error but couldn't think of how to bypass it. tried also feeding 'i' as input to plot function but then it asked to get 'e' as well, but 'e' is the event and i wasn't sure how to handle that.

any ideas?

Comment: yes. i tried def plot(e,i):

where e is the event. but i couldn't figure how to feed e as an event since in the example it's not fed to the function. but also ignoring it caused a missing argument error.

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution that satisfies me, it involves creating a class object -

hope someone finds it useful:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class plot_change():

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.i = 0
        self.fig = plt.figure(1)
        self.ax1 = self.fig.add_subplot(111,aspect='equal')


    def plot(self,e):
        self.fig = plt.figure(1)
        ax1 = self.fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
        ax1.cla()
        ax1.imshow(self.data[self.i,:,:])
        self.i += 1

    def start_plotting(self):
        cid = self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.plot)
        plt.show()


#now to see that it works
import plot_change
import torch
data = torch.rand((700,64,64))
plotter = plot_change(data)
plotter.start_plotting()
```